# Linq query performs poor according to performance analyzer in VS2012

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datetime

I've a Linq query that performs poorly:

```
var minuteValues = ValuesInMemory.Where(o => o.Key.Day == tmpValue.QuoteDate.Day &&
                                  o.Key.Hour == tmpValue.QuoteDate.Hour &&
                                  o.Key.Minute == tmpValue.QuoteDate.Minute &&
                                  o.Key.Second >= 0).Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Is there a way to do this better?

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, double> ValuesInMemory = new ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, double>();
```

`ValuesInMemory` holds about 6700 records 24/7. Every second records are added and every 2 hours the oldest values are stored in SQL Server. But the average amount of values is 6700.

Comment: could you give us more context code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the crux of your problem here is you are using the wrong tool for the job. The purpose of a dictionary is usually for *direct* retrieval i.e. give me the value associated with X key. I'm not sure how optimized they are for O(n) queries.

To rule out the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` being the bottleneck, you could try switching it out for something like a [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The last condition in your Where() expression is unnecessary and should be removed:

```
o.Key.Second >= 0
```

**Regarding performance:**

Your linq query will perform a linear scan of all the elements in your dictionary to find all "matching" keys. This is slow. In general, Dictionaries are fast when you retrieve a value by its key like this:

```
var val = dict[key];
```

It looks like you're dealing with time-series data, so instead of mapping `DateTime`s to `double`s you should make a custom class called `DataPoint` which encapsulates a value and its Timestamp.

To make this query efficient you have two options, neither are trivial:

1. Store your DataPoint objects in an ordered list and perform a
   binary search over the list using a custom `IComparer<T>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Use a dictionary to map between `DateTime`s and a ***list*** of `DataPoint`
   objects. Whenever you add a new DataPoint to the dictionary use an
   *adjusted* DateTime value as the key and add the DataPoint to the corresponding list. Generate *adjusted* DateTime values by making a new DateTime object based on the value in your DataPoint with the Second,
   and Millisecond properties set to zero. Next, you need to enforce this adjustment architecturally in one of two ways:

   - Create a new `TruncatedDateTime` type which takes a DateTime in the constructor and
     stores a truncated value. For this to work you will need to override
     the `Equals()` function and the `GetHashCode()` function so that this type
     can be used as a key in your dictionary. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden.
   - Create a `BinnedDataPoints` objects which wraps your `ValuesInMemory` dictionary and enforces DateTime value truncation whenever a new
     DataPoint is added.

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the `tmpValue.QuoteDate`'s `Day`, `Hour`, `Minute` to separate variables.

```
int day = tmpValue.QuoteDate.Day;
int hour = tmpValue.QuoteDate.Hour;
int minute = tmpValue.QuoteDate.Minute;
```

In this way these properties doesn't need to be queried each time

```
var minuteValues = ValuesInMemory.Where(o => o.Key.Day == day &&
                              o.Key.Hour == hour &&
                              o.Key.Minute == minute &&
                              o.Key.Second >= 0).Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

This can help, but maybe the compiler has optimized your query.

Comment: I really can't imagine this making much of a difference.